# Simple css positioning (I think)

Tags: html, css

I've been meaning to replace the tables in my site with css positioning and have been trying to teach myself through tutorials etc.  I've had some early success but it all came crashing down when I tried to create a sidebar.  I'm hoping the problem has some kind of simple solution.  The relative/absolute positioning of the elements is not going anywhere close to what I wanted to do.  My goal is to have a sidebar with images that stack (float?) from top to bottom, with the middle elements being part of an unordered list.  I got it to work once but now that stack on top of each other.  It has to be the way I am setting the float and the absolute/relative positioning.  After reading some articles here I tried adding a div wrapper to put them inside but I think I got myself even more confused.  Is it possible someone could nudge me in the right direction?  Here is the code:

**CSS**

```
body   
{
    background: #b6b7bc;
    font-size: .80em;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #696969;
    height: 160px;
}

a:link, a:visited
{
    color: #034af3;
}

a:hover
{
    color: #1d60ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active
{
    color: #034af3;
}

p
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}


/* HEADINGS   ----------------------------------------------------------*/

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #666666;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h1
{
    font-size: 1.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h2
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

h3
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1em;
}



/* PRIMARY LAYOUT ELEMENTS  ---------------------------------------------------------*/

.page
{
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid #496077;
}

.header
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #4b6c9e;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.header h1
{
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    border: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.main
{
    padding: 0px 12px;
    margin: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
    min-height: 420px;
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
}

.leftCol
{
    padding: 6px 0px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.footer
{
    color: #4e5766;
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
}




/* MISC ----------------------------------------------------------*/

.clear
{
    clear: both;
    width: 936px;
    height: 35px;
}

.title
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: justify;
}


.bold
{
    font-weight: bold;
}


p.clear
{
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

#wrapper
{
    position:relative;
    height: 500px;
    width: 900px;
}

#insidemain
{
    position:absolute;
    float: left;    
    width: 500px;
    height 180px;
}


/* ---------------- Sidebar Items ---------------------*/


#sidebar   /* Sidebar container */
{
    position:absolute;
    border-top: 1px solid #99CC33;
    border-left: 1px solid #99CC33;
    height: 300px;
    width: 180px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

#sidebarHeader
{
    position:absolute;
    height: 37px;
    width: 172px;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(../img/TopMenu.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#sidebarItems ul
{
    position:absolute;
    height: 27px;
    width: 172px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(../img/MenuItems.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    /*left: 6px;
    top: 45px;*/
    background-position: 0px -27px;
}

#sidebarFooter
{
    position:absolute;
    height: 46px;
    width: 172px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(../img/BottomMenu.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

And the **HTML**:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="Styles/Simple.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
            <div class="header">header
                <div class="title">
                    <h1>
                        Test Page
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class = "clear">clear</p>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="sidebar">
                    <div id="sidebarHeader">
                    </div>
                    <div id="sidebarItems">
                        <ul>
                            <li>test item</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="sidebarFooter">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="insidemain">
                main
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">clear</div>
        <div class="footer">
            <a href="http://www.google.com/">
                Blah blah test to see how far this will go across the page blah blha lorem ipsum and various other stuff that is meaningless etc
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you put your code on a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: That looks pretty cool!  I'll try messing around with that.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't have to float your div's or list. Those are block elements by default and will stack vertically regardless.

Also, as Scrimothy mentioned, you do not want absolutely positioned elements as that will take the element out of the page flow. In other words, they no longer take up "real" space in the page, and instead render at whatever coordinates you position them.

Similarly, floats also take up no space, except with other floated elements. That's why some UI developers will float almost every element on the page and "clear" them using a footer or at key breaks in the page. I personally don't recommend positioning in that fashion, but to each his own.

See if this quick tutorial helps you with some key positioning concepts: [HERE](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Comment: That quick tutorial helped quite a bit.  Thank you.  These concepts are starting to sink in a bit more.  The other thing I realized is that the preview pane in Dreamweaver is convenient but evidently doesn't behave like a typical browser like Firefox.  So now it's back to the sandbox with some simple layouts!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Typically (for non-responsive sites especially), you'd have your `.wrapper` div around the entire content (header, content, sidebar, footer, etc).  Then set your `.wrapper`s width.  Your `.sidebar` would have a set `width` and it would either `float: left;` or `float: right;` depending on the side you want it on.  Set your `.content` div's `width` which would be less than or equal to your `.wrapper width` - your `.sidebar width`.  Then add your `.clearfix` below so the `.footer` falls beneath everything. In most cases (at least for the large page chunks) you can avoid `position:absolute;` which helps make things more easily fall into place.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.  I'll also try to follow the suggestions below on making them classes.  I did a little reading on classes vs. divs and will mess with that a bit more. It's frustrating at the moment!

Comment: Yes, @Richard gives good advice too.  try to use classes for your styling hooks unless you want a default style for all `div` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Don't target the same element with both `float` and `position:absolute`. It doesn't make much sense. Anywhere where you have `float`, you should get rid of `position:absolute`

Next, get rid of those silly `class="clear"` elements. Instead, target `.footer` with `clear:both` and `.page` with `overflow-y:hidden;`

Comment: I did a tutorial in Lynda.com and when things on the page initially looked good I thought I had all figured out.  He was big on the p: clear element to "clear the float."  Clear:both would seem to make better sense since you have it in the style of the next element.

Comment: The problem isn't whether you use `clear:left` or `clear:right` - the idea of adding an element just for the `clear` property is just silly. Just understand the CSS selectors and understand the CSS properties and you don't have to resort to unusual hacks like that.